# how to get remote Workstation / VDI / server user logon dates

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, vdi

I have seen in another thread that the command ...

wmic netlogin get name, fullname, lastlogon

... will show us log on information on a Windows workstation.
Do we have a similar command for remote workstations?

Background users requests resource but will not release them if not used anymore. 
If there is no log on since a while the resource could be released.

Comment: You can run wmic against a remote computer with the /node switch. E.g. wmic /node:computer_name netlogin get name, fullname, lastlogon

Answer (score 0):

```
query user /server:<server>
```

Comment: The issue with "query" is that it allows to see the current logons only but not the logons in the past.